# Execute Server Commands on Laravel 7 Scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have 2 commands in my Laravel 7 Schelduler

```
$schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));
$schedule->exec('whoami')->everyMinute();
```

✅ The first one `works` perfectly, I get the email

[image]

---

❌ This second one doesn't work at all

> $schedule->exec('whoami')->everyMinute();

I followed: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

[image]

## Any hints for me ?

Comment: What is an output/error? Put it into try catch block and log error message.

Comment: Nothing there at all... just emptyness.

Comment: Is the user you're trying to execute that schedule with having the permissions for that directory?

Comment: @GreenPepper : How do I check that ? As you can see that when I create work around it works so I assume the same user as I would have run `whoami`

Comment: Is there a way you could access your server via SSH and execute the `whoami` command with the exact same user that your Laravel uses?

Comment: I can ssh into my server and run that commands as root and other users.

Comment: Which user laravel use ? How do I confirm that ?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check if the exec command is not disabled in php.ini. I am able to get `$schedule->exec('whoami')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('scheduler.log'), true);` working - it logs the username every minute in `/storage/scheduler.log` on fresh standard Laravel  7.30.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Clément Bisaillon suggests, you have forgotten to add method for shell command output.

but your comment has been Raised a new Question.

## Why it works with `whoiam` and `date`, but not working with `history` ?

This Works:

```
$schedule->exec('cat /home/abilogos/.bash_history ')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo('/home/abilogos/Desktop/testHist.txt');
```

you can find history file in with `echo $HISTFILE`

BUT WHY?

it gets even more interesting when you just `which history` to find history path and it tells you there

> which: no history in **Your Path**

like `source` command.

because they are not **Program**s stored in **$PATH** locations. they are **bash`s command**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html

and laravel uses php `@proc_open` (`Symfony\Component\Process\Process`) which just execute **Programs** not **Bash commands** :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: Thanks for answering, and finding the root cause - and you're correct.

Comment: @cyber8200 i think its get more useful to alter questions title, body and tag to reflect the **history** problem.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `whoami` runs fine but nothing is done with the output.

Can you try to add `emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));` to the second command to see if you get an email with the output ?

Please check the documentation about outputting the result from `exec`: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#task-output

Comment: Tried again, it seems working now, I forgot the `emailOutputTo()` on my second line, you're correct !

Comment: I've tries this `$schedule->exec('history')->everyMinute()->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));` it never works : https://i.imgur.com/PMbvkkw.png

Comment: Can you try once you on your setup? I'm not sure why `date` & `whoami` commands works

Comment: The error means that it cannot find the command 'history' on your machine. Is history an artisan command your created? If yes, you have to use `$schedule->command` instead of `$schedule->exec`

Answer (score 0):

## Temporarily

I created this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class exec extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'exec {cmd}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Run any command(s)';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $cmd = $this->argument('cmd');
        $this->info(shell_exec($cmd));
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
$schedule->command('exec date')->everyMinute()->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));
$schedule->command('exec history')->everyMinute()->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));
```

It works !!

Comment: If anyone have a better solution, please kindly post one, I would like to learn from you 

Comment: Side note: you can also check [Symfony's Process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) to be used instead shell_exec.